# JavaFX nested controls, how to get selection?

Tags: javafx

I try to implement an application with JavaFX 8 where I have a ListView of GridPanes, where each GridPane consists of 2 other controls (ChoiceBoxes). The Gridpanes in the ListView are dynamically added by the user during runtime. What I like to achive is to add a listener to the ChoiceBox such that I know to which ListView item/index the selected choicebox belongs to if a user makes a choice.

My Problem is now that I cannot get the index of the ListView when the user selects an item of the choicebox, because the item (i.e. the Gridpane) in ListView is not (automatically) selected or focused in this case.

Can anybode help me with this?

Comment: You can search through parents until you find it?

Comment: Add listener when you constructing the choiceboxes in your custom list cell factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I got the solution now by looking for the parent of the choicebox (note that paneList is an ArrayList in which I stored the references to the GridPanes which where added by the user)

```
    // define Listener for choiceBox
    choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        GridPane parent = (GridPane) choiceBox.getParent();
        // keep track of selected choice
        selectedChoice = newValue;
        logger.debug("selected choice: {}", selectedChoice);

        // keep also track of parent GridPane
        selectedGridpane = paneList.indexOf(parent);
        logger.debug("selected GridPane {}", paneList.indexOf(parent));
    });
```